# Using /etc/hosts with docker

Tags: apache, docker, containers

On my Mac I use vagrant with Ubuntu and apache running on it, and have virtual host entries for my various code repositories for apache. In the OSX side of things I create /etc/hosts entries for each of those v-host entries.

I'm trying to achieve the same effect with docker, but I'm struggling to figure it out without having to specify the port number when accessing the app, which I don't want to do. Ex: I have `127.0.0.1 dockertest.com` in my /etc/hosts, which I can then access at `http://dockertest.com:8080`. I'd like to be able to just go to `http://dockertest.com` without specifying the port. How can I achieve this? I know port numbers can't be used in the /etc/hosts file, so I'm looking for a way that would mimic the effect if it was possible. I need to be able to run multiple docker apps at the same time because some of the codebases communicate with one another and each need to have their own unique hostname, so I don't think simply setting ports to `80:80` in the docker-compose file will work because every app will be (attempting) to run on `127.0.0.1:80`.

For context I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/) for running apache, php and mysql on docker. All of my files are exactly as shown on that site.

**Update**

I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` nginx error with the following `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=dockertest.com
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

**Update 2**

Resolved the '502 Bad Gateway' error, here's the updated `docker-compose.yml` file. I had to add the nginx-proxy to one of the networks I referenced. My question isn't completely resolved, but I do have part of it working. For anyone reading this looking for a solution, I created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446765/running-multiple-docker-compose-files-with-nginx-reverse-proxy) to prevent this one from getting too long.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=dockertest.com
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), it's a reverse proxy auto-configured by the env vars of other containers, so you don't need to manually write nginx proxy configs. Also as requested, it allows to use specific port to forward requests to.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'

services:

  lamp:
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: some_domain.dev
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 9999
    image: my_lamp_image

  app:
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: another_domain.dev
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 3000
    image: my_app_image

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

```
# /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 some_domain.dev
127.0.0.1 another_domain.dev
```

`jwilder/nginx-proxy` has many more nice features like ssl, uwsgi, fastcgi and can also be used in production. There are also "companion" additions like [let's encrypt ssl](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) and [man in the middle proxy](https://github.com/artemkloko/docker-mitm-nginx-proxy-companion).

Comment: Is there a way to do this method but with multiple docker-compose files, one for each of my repositories? I was able to get this to work, but I'm dealing with 20+ repositories and not all of them are related to each other and some are using different versions of PHP, so having them all in one docker-compose file doesn't make sense for my case. As soon as one is running, then port 80 is already blocked and I can't run a second app with its own docker-compose file. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is. But please either open a new question or update the original with the extra requirements. The explanation won't look nice it in the comments...

Comment: I updated my post with my docker-compose.yml file. I thought I had it working, but I realized that I left `ports 80:80` in the apache service section of `docker-compose.yml`, so it wasn't really nginx doing the proxy. After removing that I'm getting a '502 Bad Gateway' error

Comment: Your `apache` is in 2 networks - frontend and backend. Your `nginx` is in 1 network - default (because you didn't add any network entries to it, it was added to a "default"). In order for those two containers to communicate they need to be in the same network. So either remove all the network references from `docker-compose.yml`, or add `nginx-proxy` to one of the networks that `apache` is in.

Comment: thanks, both of your suggestions work. Do you suggest leaving the networks or removing them? I created a new post here as you suggested, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446765/running-multiple-docker-compose-files-with-nginx-reverse-proxy

Comment: Glad to help. If you plan to use those docker-compose files only locally, then there is no need for networks. Docker networks offer isolation between containers, so they are very advisable for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your apache server runs on port 80 inside the container. If you want use `dockertest.com` outside with your /etc/hosts entry, than u have to use port 80 for outside also.

1. make your `/etc/hosts` entry for the dockertest.com domain
2. If you use docker, run it with `-p 80:80`or if you use docker-compose

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to be able to run multiple docker apps at the same time, some are microservices that interact with each other. Won't that limit me to only being able to run 1 docker app at a time?

Comment: if all your services should run on port 80, then you are in fact limited to 1 docker app at a time. You can use a reverse proxy in front of your docker services to run multiple services with http or https. I would recommend you [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) for this.

Comment: but I can specify different port numbers to run multiple apps. Ex: `8080:80`, `8081:80` and then access at something like `http://dockertest.com:8080` and `http://dockertest2.com:8081`. I'm trying to achieve that result, but without having to specify the port number in the url. If that's not the "docker way" of doing things, how should I go about being able to give each of my apps unique hostnames without having to specify a port in the url?

Comment: there is no the docker way. You have two choices - 1. run your services on different ports - 2. Use a server with virtualhost configuration or a reverse proxy in front of. Have a look on the traefik documentation.

Comment: When you say " run your services on different ports", do you mean specifying the port number in the url like `http://dockertest2.com:8081`? If so, sounds like #2 is my only option.

Comment: yes, #1 dockertest1.com:8080, dockertest2.com:8081 or #2 dockertest1.com, dockertest2.com

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to set up all the applications in their separate containers and then connecting them via a [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

And in order to reach all of the containers I would suggest adding an nginx webserver container to the network as a reverse proxy, which you can then bind to port 80 of your machine.

You can then either define a `location` for every app separately ot define one generic location like

```
# sample.conf
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name ~ (?<docker_host_name>.+);
  location ~ {
    # for actual request forwarding
    proxy_pass                         http://$docker_host_name$1$is_args$args;
    # some stuff I figured out I have to use in order for service to work properly
    proxy_set_header                   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header                   Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_http_version                 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

This configuration either has to be placed inline in the original `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or in a separate file that is included inside the `http` config block.

After restarting the nginx service or container (depending on container setup) you should be able to reach all the services inside the docker network and all of the services should be able to communicate to each other without problems.

Of course you still have to keep the entries in the hosts file, so your computer knows that it has to process the request locally.

## Edit:

The original config (probably) does not do what it is supposed to do.
So, I came up with a newer version, which should get the job done:

```
# sample.conf
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location ~ {
    # for actual request forwarding
    proxy_pass                         http://$host$1$is_args$args;
    # some stuff I figured out I have to use in order for service to work properly
    proxy_set_header                   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header                   Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_http_version                 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

With this configuration, the nginx server will be listening to all incoming requests on port 80 and forward them to the proper container inside the network.
You also do not have to configure the host resolution yourself, as docker container names also represent the host(-name) of a container.

Hopefully this works out for you.

Comment: the tutorial I linked uses an overlay network for the 3 services (apache, php, mysql). Is that what you're referring to by connecting the containers? If so, do you have any resources for me to read up on specifically what you're referring to with nginx? Even just some terms for me to look up would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Exactly. By connecting the containers inside a docker network they can communicate via their host names which correspond to their container names.

Hope that helped

But, sine you cannot bind multiple containers to port 80 you have to have a service which decides, what app is going to be served. For these things you use a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

It is possible to use Apache, but [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) is almost always the web server of choice when it comes down to setting up a reverse proxy.

Comment: would this solution require putting all of my code repositories into one docker-compose file, or can I keep separate docker-compose files for each of my repositories? I tried artemkloko's answer using the jwilder/nginx-proxy service, but it appears to require putting all of my repositories into one docker-compose file as individual services. I'd prefer to keep them separate, because not all of them are related to each other and some even use different php versions. Additionally, some I rarely even use, so keeping that service running at all times isn't ideal for me. Thanks again

Comment: I just added a new config block to my answer. That config should in fact allow you to run all of your apps in separate containers (with separate compose files) while enabling inter container communication. So, you should not have to change any of your files, but set up a simple nginx container with the shown second config in place. Hope that helps