# Running multiple docker-compose files with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: apache, docker, nginx

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435997/using-etc-hosts-with-docker/55441120?noredirect=1#comment97606931_55441120) and got part of my problem solved, but I was advised to create another question because it started to get a bit lengthy in the comments.

I'm trying to use docker to run multiple PHP,MySQL & Apache based apps on my Mac, all of which would use different `docker-compose.yml` files (more details in the post I linked). I have quite a few repositories, some of which communicate with one another, and not all of them are the same PHP version. Because of this, I don't think it's wise for me to cram 20+ separate repositories into one single docker-compose.yml file. I'd like to have separate docker-compose.yml files for each repository and I want to be able to use an `/etc/hosts` entry for each app so that I don't have to specify the port. Ex: I would access 2 different repositories such as `http://dockertest.com` and `http://dockertest2.com` (using `/etc/hosts` entries), rather than having to specify the port like `http://dockertest.com:8080` and `http://dockertest.com:8081`.

Using the accepted answer from my other post I was able to get one app running at a time (one docker-compose.yml file), but if I try to launch another with `docker-compose up -d` it results in an error because port 80 is already taken. How can I runn multiple docker apps at the same time, each with their own `docker-compose.yml` files and without having to specify the port in the url?

Here's a docker-compose.yml file for the app I made. In my `/etc/hosts` I have `127.0.0.1 dockertest.com`

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html/:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=dockertest.com
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest to extract the `nginx-proxy` to a separate `docker-compose.yml` and create a repository for the "reverse proxy" configuration with the following:

A file with extra contents to add to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 dockertest.com
127.0.0.1 anothertest.com
127.0.0.1 third-domain.net
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` which will have only the reverse proxy

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Next, as you already mentioned, create a `docker-compose.yml` for each of your repositories that act as web endpoints. You will need to add `VIRTUAL_HOST` env var to the services that serve your applications (eg. Apache).

The `nginx-proxy` container can run in "permanent mode", as it has a small footprint. This way whenever you start a new container with `VIRTUAL_HOST` env var, the configuration of `nginx-proxy` will be automatically updated to include the new local domain. (You will still have to update `/etc/hosts` with the new entry).

---

If you decide to use networks, your web endpoint containers will have to be in the same network as `nginx-proxy`, so your docker-compose files will have to be modified similar to this:

```
# nginx-proxy/docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
networks:
  reverse-proxy:
```

```
# service1/docker-compose.yml

version: "3.3"
services:
  php1:
    ...
    networks:
      - backend1
  apache1:
    ...
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy_reverse-proxy
      - backend1
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=dockertest.com
  mysql1:
    ...
    networks:
      - backend1
networks:
  backend1:
  nginx-proxy_reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

```
# service2/docker-compose.yml

version: "3.3"
services:
  php2:
    ...
    networks:
      - backend2
  apache2:
    ...
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy_reverse-proxy
      - backend2
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=anothertest.com
  mysql2:
    ...
    networks:
      - backend2
networks:
  backend2:
  nginx-proxy_reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

The `reverse-proxy` network that is created in `nginx-proxy/docker-compose.yml` is referred as `nginx-proxy_reverse-proxy` in the other docker-compose files because whenever you define a network - its final name will be `{{folder name}}_{{network name}}`

---

If you want to have a look at a solution that relies on browser proxy extension instead of `/etc/hosts`, check out [mitm-proxy-nginx-companion](https://github.com/artemkloko/docker-mitm-nginx-proxy-companion)

Comment: Awesome, that was surprisingly easy! Thanks so much for the help, I can't believe how quick and easy it is to get set up and running compared to my current local dev environment.